# Can I use t-statistic as feature importance in linear regression?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, regression-coefficients

[Here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/limo.html) it is mentioned that $\frac{\hat \beta_j}{SE(\hat \beta_j)}$ can be used as feature importance. Is this correct and can I then compare my features?

Once I have a linear regression model, I would like to compare relative importance of one feature vs. another. How can I do this?

Tree based methods are able to do this, but for linear regression it seems to get tricky if not all data is on same scale

**Note that I do not wish to standardize these variables since I would like to make my answers interpretable**

Comment: Why can't you interpret a standardized variable?

Comment: because it becomes harder to interpret that way, i have a mix of binary and continuous so i dont think it makes sense to standardize binary columns too ?

Comment: e.g. gender is binary [0,1], and another indepdenet variabe is weight.. so i have different scale, if i standardize all columns it doesn't make sense to do this to binary columns to in order to compare